# What is going on here when I try installing the facial recognition library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, face-recognition

```
C:\Users\Peter>pip install face-recognition
Collecting face-recognition
  Using cached face_recognition-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 in c:\users\peter\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from face-recognition) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\peter\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from face-recognition) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\peter\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from face-recognition) (7.2.0)
Collecting dlib>=19.7
  Using cached dlib-19.20.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: Click>=6.0 in c:\users\peter\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from face-recognition) (7.1.2)
Using legacy setup.py install for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dlib, face-recognition
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1wn8ktik\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1wn8ktik\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s9fezs_8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wn8ktik\dlib\
    Complete output (55 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wn8ktik\dlib\setup.py", line 120, in get_cmake_version
        out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
        return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wn8ktik\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wn8ktik\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
        cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
      File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wn8ktik\dlib\setup.py", line 122, in get_cmake_version
        raise RuntimeError("\n*******************************************************************\n" +
    RuntimeError:
    *******************************************************************
     CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
    *******************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1wn8ktik\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1wn8ktik\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s9fezs_8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: run "pip install cmake", and then run install requirements

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that cmake IS INSTALLED, and it still won't work